# Getting TypeError: t.filter is not a function when application is deployed in heroku

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, sequelize.js, vuetify.js

I have developed a web application using VueJS 2 , sequelize 5.22, Vuetify 2.4, Postgres , NodeJS 15.12 and ExpressJS 4.16 . the application works fine and tested completely in local machine and running without any error and issue.

After deploying in Heroku, although the application is running and showing all pages, and connected to Postgres database, However  data is not coming up in v-data-table on pages and there are below error

**TypeError: t.filter is not a function**

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4tec.png)

on Server side , this is controller for getting list of data:

```
    async index(req, res) {
        try {
            const currency = await Currency.findAll();          
            res.send(currency)
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(400).send({
                error: 'Error in showing list of currencies ...'
            })
        }
    },
```

and in client side , using this code  :

```
   async mounted() {
            this.currencies = (await CurrencyService.index()).data;
            
        },
```

Please let me know how I could fix this issue

Comment: Please provide the code where `t` is defined, and where `t.filter` is called

Comment: I have not defined t in my code

Comment: The error you are getting is telling you just that then, if t is not defined... then it cant be a function :)

Comment: So there is no error when I run locally on my PC